Connect SecretManager from CustomResource docker image fails with timeout
I use a typescript CDK. Inside this I added a custome resource step. A sockerfile with a simple Javascript inside. It is working well until I want to receive the the connection string to my postgres database from SecretManager.
I use the following code in my stack:
      this.urlSecret = new Secret(this, 'db-url-secret', {
        secretStringValue: new SecretValue(
            `postgres://${databaseUsername}:${password}@${
                this.dbCluster.clusterEndpoint.hostname
            }:${this.dbCluster.clusterEndpoint.port.toString()}/${props.databaseName}?schema=public`,
        ),
        });  


      const initializer = new CdkResourceInitializer(this, 'MyRdsInit', {
        config: this.urlSecret.secretName, //<-Name I use in docker to get secret.
        fnLogRetention: RetentionDays.FIVE_MONTHS,
        fnCode: DockerImageCode.fromImageAsset(`${__dirname}/rds-init-fn-code`, {}),
        fnTimeout: Duration.minutes(2),
        fnSecurityGroups: [],
        vpc: props.vpc,
        subnetsSelection: props.vpc.selectSubnets({
            subnetType: cdk.aws_ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC
            }),
        });     

        initializer.customResource.node.addDependency(this.dbCluster);
        this.dbCluster.connections.allowFrom(initializer.function, Port.tcp(5432));
        this.dbCluster.connections.allowDefaultPortFromAnyIpv4();
        this.urlSecret.grantRead(initializer.function);

    }

When I run the code with the fowlloing javascript inside the docker container:
const pg = require('pg');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path')
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')

const secrets = new AWS.SecretsManager({})

exports.handler = async (e) => {

    const { config } = e.params
    var conString = "<connection  string>";
    //config is the secret Name;

    console.log('#############DOCKER');
    console.log(config);    

    const { conn } = await getSecretValue(config)
    console.log(conn);

    var client = new pg.Client(conString);
    await client.connect();

    const sql = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'script.sql')).toString()

    var res = await client.query(sql);

    await client.end();  

    return {
      status: 'OK',
      results: ''
    }

}

function getSecretValue (secretId) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
    secrets.getSecretValue({ SecretId: secretId }, (err, data) => {
      if (err) return reject(err)

      return resolve(JSON.parse(data.SecretString))
    })
  })
}

I get alsways a Timout error with the function: getSecretValue.
I re-check everything a couple of times but it seems that the docker image cannot receive the SecretManager or connect to it.
2024-09-13T09:48:49.341Z    7d8d9575-d4c9-4510-992d-a997677a188f    ERROR   Invoke Error    
{
    "errorType": "TimeoutError",
    "errorMessage": "connect ETIMEDOUT 18.179.209.155:443",
    "code": "TimeoutError",
    "message": "connect ETIMEDOUT 18.179.209.155:443",
    "errno": -110,
    "syscall": "connect",
    "address": "18.179.209.155",
    "port": 443,
    "time": "2024-09-13T09:48:49.340Z",
    "region": "ap-northeast-1",
    "hostname": "secretsmanager.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com",
    "retryable": true,
    "stack": [
        "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 18.179.209.155:443",
        "    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1159:16)"
    ]
}

BEcause I use a public subnet I assume that the docker can connect to the SecretManager.
Iam sure that I have missed something. Can anybody give me a hint or sample?

Ensure your VPC has an internet gateway attached. Verify that the public subnet has a route table that routes 0.0.0.0/0 traffic to the internet gateway.
Check IAM role associated with the container has proper permissions to access Secrets Manager, such as secretsmanager:GetSecretValue.
if can't resolve, I sugget you to add VPC Endpoint
